# Decomposition of a matrix into a product of two-level unitaries

Tags: matrices, quantum-computation

I am working through example 4.12 and 4.13 from ['Quantum Computing: From Linear Algebra to Physical Realizations'](http://213.55.83.214:8181/Computer%20Science/collection/00342.pdf) (Pages 83-84 and 405-406) and I can't seem to figure out some what the '*' in figure (i) and (ii) mean?

Comment: It probably means the complex conjugate.

Comment: I think you are right, I searched the book and found a footnote saying it means 'Hermitian conjugate'